# how to disable vibrator in android phone programatically

Tags: android

I'm trying to disable the vibrator using `vibrator.cancel()` but it is not working. How should I disable it? I have tried following code:

```
Vibrator vib = (Vibrator) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
vib.cancel()
```

Comment: can you share the scenario in which you are usnig vibrator?

Comment: `cancel()` is used to stop any existing vibrate calls. If you want to disable vibrations system-wide, you need to look into `setVibrateSetting()` in [AudioManager](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can enable and disable vibrator like this

```
AudioManager vib = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
```

***Enable silent mode***

```
vib.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

***Disable silent mode***

```
vib..setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
```

it may be help you or someone else

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,,it will help

```
switch (position) {
    case 0:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
        break;
    case 1:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
        break;
    case 2:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, 
                AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
        break;
    case 3:
        audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL);
        audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, 
                AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_ON);
        break;
    }
```